# Is there a better way to make multiple JavaScript replace calls than doing them one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, performance, replace

I'm constructing a string in Javascript which will contain HTML.

Right now, I'm doing something like this:

```
var filter = "";
filter = util.getTemplate( "tmp_filter", temps );
filter = filter.replace( 'id="tmp_filter"','');
if (dyn.table.i18n) {
    filter = filter.replace(util.regex.re_text, dyn.filter.clear_tx);
} else {
    filter = filter.replace('data-i18n="[title]tmp_text"', 'title="'+dyn.filter.clear_tx+'" ');
    filter = filter.replace('data-i18n="tmp_text">','>'+dyn.filter.clear_tx);
}
filter = filter.replace(util.regex.re_theme, dyn.filter.theme);
filter = filter.replace(util.regex.re_icon, dyn.filter.icon);
filter = filter.replace(util.regex.re_iconpos, dyn.filter.iconpos);
filter = filter.replace('class="ui-listview-filter ', 'class="ui-listview-filter '+ dyn.custom_classes[0]+' ');
```

Which pulls a template and replaces all placeholders with data specified in `dyn`.

While this works, it's an awful lot of replace calls. In SQL, I can nest replace calls like this

```
SELECT LEN(REPLACE(REPLACE(address, ' CA', ''), ' NY', '')) FROM Tbl
```

**Question:**
Is there a better way in Javascript to do multiple `replace` calls? I don't mind the length of the code, but I'm a little uneasy with `filter = filter.replace`. Just wondering if there is a better way to do?

Thanks!

Comment: you can chain all replaces

Comment: ok. Trying this. Thanks

Comment: Please make it answer, so I can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain all the replaces